# High chart React Native not working for me

Tags: javascript, git, react-native, highcharts, expo

I have tried different methods to import and use high chart in react native android mobile app but each causes some error like:

1. Error loading page,Domain : unknown, Error code :-1 ,Description :net:: ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED.
2. Some time blank expo page
3. etc but nothing works for me.

Can any one share the react native new HighChart git project?

Comment: The issue is known problem reported in our github -> https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native/issues/51 please share your details there.

Comment: Failed to compile
C:/Users/admin/React Native Project/TestGhost/node_modules/@highcharts/highcharts-react-native/src/HighchartsReactNative.js 158:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (158:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
@SebastianBochan